# Get Network status for each interface separately

Tags: netstat, vnstat

I'm trying to get statistics for each interface (NIC)and protocol separately, I know about nstat and netstats but they give me all interfaces and protocols statics together, is there any way to get those statistics grouped by interface name and protocol?